# Where to declare variable in React Component

Tags: html, reactjs, jus

I am trying to declare the variable images inside the component but it shown error .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KJAU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove **let**

you are working with class component ,don't need to explicit inside classes and when you need to call it do like this :

> this.images